# How to stop Windows from overriding Alt modifier key?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding, blender

I use an application (Blender) that makes use of a keyboard shortcut (Alt S) that is in conflict with Windows 8. The expected behavior is that **Alt S** will trigger the *"Shrink/Fatten Geometry"* function, but instead it brings up some unwanted OS-specific menu. At least this is what happens on my student's computer. I use OS X at home and don't have this problem on my machines. This shortcut conflict is really a nuisance. Since I don't use Windows at home I don't have a chance to play with the OS settings and try to figure out the fix for this.

Can somebody please explain (so that even a non Windows-user can understand) what the steps are for disabling this OS-specific menu being brought up whenever **Alt S** is pressed? Thank you.

Update: Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: What menu exactly does it pop up? Can you quote any of the menu items? Windows has generally avoided using Alt for new OS-wide shortcuts ever since the "Windows" key in 1998...

Comment: @grawity I wish I could give a more specific description of the menu now, but it's navigation-related. I think it includes application shortcuts. I'm always so irritated by it that I'm mostly concerned with how to get rid of it and I don't look at the details. I can post a pic in a day or so.

Comment: Please do. I'm 95% sure it's a third-party app. (Google results suggest it's HP's shovelware.)

Comment: @grawity Here's a pic... Based on your feedback and the "Like IObit" button I think it's clear that this is caused by some malware called IObit. I will probably just tell them "sorry, your computer is F'd, get a Mac or install Linux", but if there's a reliable way to uninstall this crapware I'd like to know how. [From what I've seen](https://malwaretips.com/threads/what-is-the-best-way-to-completely-remove-all-iobit-products.38712/) everyone has a different opinion on what the best way is to remove it.